# Make a Mikrotik Router behave as a separate router on each port

Tags: mikrotik, routeros

We use Mikrotik routers for many points in our system, but we have an odd need for one location.

We would like to use one router (example: RB960PGS-PB), where the main Internet connection comes in on port 1, and have ports 2-5 each act as a separate public-facing router.

IE, each port will be assigned a custom MAC, will have a public IP bound (we have a large pool of public IPs), and on the "inside" it will act like a normal router (firewall, dhcp for 192.168.x.x or 10.x.x.x, etc..).

Is this even possible? We are using Ubiquiti Lite APs on each of the ports (2-5) but we would like each AP to act like a separate router/network with its own public IP.

There are site restrictions that prevent us from just putting an AirCube, Linksys, or other cheap router between the Mikrotik site router and the AP.

Comment: The concept of VLAN come after, as all those port you can uplink them to dedicated switch, or to a distribution switch with VLAN per port to isolate those traffic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this even possible?

Yes. That's literally what a router is. The term "router" has become diluted over the past 15 years to mean almost anything. It often means "Router/Switch/WiFi Access Point/DHCP Server/Firewall". But the "Routing" part of it is the part you need.

In your MikroTik, remove the ports from "bridge" interface. Bam. You no longer have a switch, you have all the individual ports acting independently.

Note that, being a router, you will still be able to access the other subnets as the router will say "Oh I know how to get to that network" and will just forward the packets. If you don't want this, if you want each port to be isolated, then you'll need to configure the firewall on your Mikrotik to deny the cross-interface traffic.

Comment: And also if you want to have different routes for each interface, you should do source-routing either by using route-marks in the firewall mangle or using route rules.

Comment: Marking this as the correct, since it was closest. We had an issue where we could not get the routing tables to correctly sync, but seem to have it worked out now.